# Is there any feature in JEE8 for cancelling HTTP 2 request processing

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee

HTTP 1.1 doesn't have any mechanism to ask the server to cancel a request. It is possible to get the input/output/error stream from `HttpURLConnection` and close them. That would throw `IOException` on the client side allowing the client to clean up after cancel. The "persistent" or "keepAlive" TCP connection of HTTP 1.1 will continue to exist for future requests. Therefore, the server doesn't get to know about these events on the client side until it tries to write and fails.

HTTP 2 provides a separate frame called `RST_STREAM` to close a stream or cancel a fired request. Since the Java 9 `HttpClient` allows us to make asynchronous HTTP request returning a `CompletableFuture`, there is now a more elegant way to cancel an ongoing request using the `cancel()` method of `CompletableFuture`.

My questions:

1. Does Java 9+ releases actually send the `RST_STREAM` to the server when `cancel()` is invoked?
2. Does JEE8 provide any mechanishm to interrupt the business logic executing against the HTTP request on receipt of the `RST_STREAM`? Or any plan for future releases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 11 to cancel an HTTP/2 request with the `java.net.HttpClient` you would have to provide your own `BodySubscriber` (or wrap one of the provided built-in) and cancel the `Flow.Subscription`. This should reset the HTTP/2 stream.

Comment: Note that since Java 16 you may call cancel(true) on the `CompletableFuture` returned by `HttpClient::sendAsync` and this will attempt to cancel the underlying operation. The call to the cancel method may however return before the underlying operations have actually been cancelled.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html#sendAsync(java.net.http.HttpRequest,java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandler,java.net.http.HttpResponse.PushPromiseHandler)

Comment: Interrupting the thread that calls `HttpClient::send` should also work in the same way.